# std::smatch str() not returning correct string

Tags: c++, regex

I decided to make my own regex.h containing a class with some methods for an easier way to check, and parse strings using regexes.

The first version of my .h included just some methods, which worked just fine. Later, I decided to organize all those methods in one class, everything worked fine, but, at some point, the "match_str" method started returning strings that were of the correct length, but only consisting of "|" characters, for some reason.

This is the whole regex.h file:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

class regex { 
    std::vector<std::smatch> match;
public: 
    regex(std::string);

    std::regex r;

    int generate_matches(std::string s) {
        auto matches_begin = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
        auto matches_end = std::sregex_iterator();
        for (std::sregex_iterator i = matches_begin; i != matches_end; ++i) { match.push_back(*i); }
        return match.size();
    }

    bool matches(std::string s) {
        return std::regex_search(s, r);
    }

    int match_count() {
        return match.size();
    }

    std::string match_str(int index = 0, int group = 0) {
        return match.size() ? match.at(index)[group].str() : "";
    }

    int match_pos(int index = 0) {
        return match.at(index).position() + 1;
    }
}; regex::regex(std::string regex) : r(regex) {}
```

Everything but the "match_str" method seems to work fine

This code:

```
int main() {
    regex rx("(int|long)( +)([a-z]);");
    if (rx.generate_matches("int a; int b; int c;")) {
        std::cout << rx.match_str() + "\n";
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Outputs:

```
¦¦¦¦¦¦
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I tried that code. It returns "int a;" as expected. Maybe just clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: It looks like you are saving iterators into a container that has gone out of scope. You might try saving the actual data instead. If so it's undefined behavior, so it might seem to work in some cases but not others and not on different compilers/platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects of `match_results` keep `const iterator` or `const char*` pointer to the matched string. In `generate_matches` string `s` object is local variable so it is deleted when function terminates, you cannot store const iterator or pointer of local variable to vector - you will have dangling pointer, and it is undefined behaviour when you try to read data of object which was destroyed.

You can add additional variable to your `regex` class and change your `generate_matches` function as follows:

```
class regex { 
  std::vector<std::smatch> match;
  std::string str; // <---

int generate_matches(std::string s) {
    str = s; // <---
    auto matches_begin = std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), r); // <--- 
    auto matches_end = std::sregex_iterator();
    for (std::sregex_iterator i = matches_begin; i != matches_end; ++i) { match.push_back(*i); }
    return match.size();
}
```

now you can call `match_str` function and read `match` vector because `smatch` objects refer to existing object - `str`, not temporary.